# Error: [Errno 13] Permission Denied with python3 virtual env

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, permissions

I'm following this guide here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django

In order to get a better feel for django. Everything was going smoothly until I get to the part where I put "python -3 venv .venv" into the terminal, this is where I get the error:

Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jstone/hello_django/.venv/pyvenv.cfg'

If I put sudo before the command, things will go smoothly until I get to vs code where I will again be hit with a bunch of permission errors when trying to use pip. Things will work if I put myself as a superuser but when I try to activate vs code I then get this error:

you are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument.

Sorry, I'm somewhat new to doing anything like this so I'm finding it a bit confusing.. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to empower the related folder directly with this command:

```
sudo chown -R username /path/to/working/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem
you should use this command line:(use space after '.' is a key)

'' . venv/bin/activate ''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).